# Scheduler not load on initial

Tags: telerik, scheduler

I have a problem, I'm new to php telerik, the scheduler it working for save, delete and update, but this not show data on first time, I'm using Mysql.
I'm using the example from the official website http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/scheduler/resources

Thanks for your help

```php
  <?php
    require_once '../lib/DataSourceResult.php';
    require_once '../lib/SchedulerDataSourceResult.php';
    require_once '../lib/Kendo/Autoload.php';


    $columns = array('MeetingID', 'Title', 'Start', 'End', 'StartTimezone', 'EndTimezone', 'IsAllDay', 'Description', 'RecurrenceID', 'RecurrenceRule', 'RecurrenceException', 'RoomID');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        //$result = new SchedulerDataSourceResult('sqlite:..//sample.db');
        $result = new SchedulerDataSourceResult('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'password');

        $type = $_GET['type'];



        switch($type) {
            case 'create':
                $result = $result->createWithAssociation('Meetings', 'MeetingAttendees', $columns, $request->models, 'MeetingID', array('Attendees' => 'AttendeeID'));
                break;
            case 'update':
                $result = $result->updateWithAssociation('Meetings', 'MeetingAttendees', $columns, $request->models, 'MeetingID', array('Attendees' => 'AttendeeID'));
                break;
            case 'destroy':
                $result = $result->destroyWithAssociation('Meetings', 'MeetingAttendees', $request->models, 'MeetingID');
                break;
            default:
                $result = $result->readWithAssociation('Meetings', 'MeetingAttendees', 'MeetingID', array('AttendeeID' => 'Attendees'), array('MeetingID', 'RoomID'), $request);
                break;
        }

        echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

        exit;
    }

    require_once '../include/header.php';

    $transport = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransport();

    $create = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportCreate();

    $create->url('resources.php?type=create')
         ->contentType('application/json')
         ->type('POST');

    $read = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportRead();

    $read->url('resources.php?type=read')
         ->contentType('application/json')
         ->type('POST');


    $update = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportUpdate();

    $update->url('resources.php?type=update')
         ->contentType('application/json')
         ->type('POST');

    $destroy = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportDestroy();

    $destroy->url('resources.php?type=destroy')
         ->contentType('application/json')
         ->type('POST');

    $transport->create($create)
              ->read($read)
              ->update($update)
              ->destroy($destroy)
              ->parameterMap('function(data) {
                  return kendo.stringify(data);
              }');

    $model = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModel();

    $meetingIdField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('meetingID');
    $meetingIdField->type('number')
                ->from('MeetingID')
                ->nullable(true);

    $titleField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('title');
    $titleField->from('Title')
            ->defaultValue('No title')
            ->validation(array('required' => true));

    $startField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('start');
    $startField->type('date')
            ->from('Start');

    $startTimezoneField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('startTimezone');
    $startTimezoneField->from('StartTimezone');

    $endField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('end');
    $endField->type('date')
            ->from('End');

    $endTimezoneField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('endTimezone');
    $endTimezoneField->from('EndTimezone');

    $isAllDayField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('isAllDay');
    $isAllDayField->type('boolean')
            ->from('IsAllDay');

    $descriptionField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('description');
    $descriptionField->type('string')
            ->from('Description');

    $recurrenceIdField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('recurrenceId');
    $recurrenceIdField->from('RecurrenceID');

    $recurrenceRuleField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('recurrenceRule');
    $recurrenceRuleField->from('RecurrenceRule');

    $recurrenceExceptionField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('recurrenceException');
    $recurrenceExceptionField->from('RecurrenceException');

    $roomIdField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('roomId');
    $roomIdField->from('RoomID')
            ->nullable(true);

    $attendeesField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('attendees');
    $attendeesField->from('Attendees')
            ->defaultValue([]);

    $model->id('meetingID')
        ->addField($meetingIdField)
        ->addField($titleField)
        ->addField($startField)
        ->addField($endField)
        ->addField($startTimezoneField)
        ->addField($endTimezoneField)
        ->addField($descriptionField)
        ->addField($recurrenceIdField)
        ->addField($recurrenceRuleField)
        ->addField($recurrenceExceptionField)
        ->addField($roomIdField)
        ->addField($attendeesField)
        ->addField($isAllDayField);

    $schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
    $schema->data('data')
            ->errors('errors')
            ->model($model);

    $dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();

    $dataSource->transport($transport)
        ->schema($schema)
        ->batch(true);

    $roomResource = new \Kendo\UI\SchedulerResource();
    $roomResource->field('roomId')
        ->title('Room')
        ->dataSource(array(
            array('text'=> 'Meeting Room 101', 'value' => 1, 'color' => '#6eb3fa'),
            array('text'=> 'Meeting Room 201', 'value' => 2, 'color' => '#f58a8a')
        ));

    $attendeesResource = new \Kendo\UI\SchedulerResource();
    $attendeesResource->field('attendees')
        ->title('Attendees')
        ->multiple(true)
        ->dataSource(array(
            array('text'=> 'Alex', 'value' => 1, 'color' => '#f8a398'),
            array('text'=> 'Bob', 'value' => 2, 'color' => '#51a0ed'),
            array('text'=> 'Charlie', 'value' => 3, 'color' => '#56ca85')
        ));


    $scheduler = new \Kendo\UI\Scheduler('scheduler');
    $scheduler->timezone("Etc/UTC")
            ->date(new DateTime('2013/6/13'))
            ->height(600)
            ->addResource($roomResource, $attendeesResource)
            ->addView(array('type' => 'day', 'startTime' => new DateTime('2013/6/13 7:00')),
                array('type' => 'week', 'selected' => true, 'startTime' => new DateTime('2013/6/13 7:00')), 'month', 'agenda', 'timeline')
            ->dataSource($dataSource);

    echo $scheduler->render();
    ?>

    <?php require_once '../include/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What there is a telerik php ?

Comment: yes, is there.http://www.telerik.com/php-ui